# Need tab in jQuery Grid

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, grid

I am using jQuery grid and I need to switch between the cells using the tab key. I need to show my data from a database and that's why I need to use a grid.

Please suggest me how to achieve this. I am using spring MVC on the backend.

```
function setupGrid(){
    jQuery("#dataTable").jqGrid({
        url: "data/person/get",
        datatype: "json",
        jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, id: "ref"},
        colNames:['ID','First Name','Last Name', 'Address', 'Postcode'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'id',index:'id', width:20},
            {name:'firstName',index:'firstName', width:100},
            {name:'lastName',index:'lastName', width:100},
            {name:'address',index:'address', width:380},
            {name:'postcode',index:'postcode', width:100}
        ],
        rowNum:5,
        rowList:[5,10,20],
        height:165,
        pager: "#pagingDiv",
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: "Names and Addresses"
    });
}
```

This is the code I am using to setup my grid and show the data I am working on. This is POC where I need tab index in my tabular data.

Comment: please suggest what grid i need to use to achieve it

Comment: do you mean you need to visualize the tab `\t` character? Usually HTML does not tolerate any __literal__ whitespaces

Comment: @lvaylo Slavov - No i want tab index in my data that i am showing on my grid, grid showing the data but dont have tab index so i need tab index

Comment: i am unable to get any code to set tab inside the jqgrid so please suggest where or in which grid structure i can add tab index in my tabular data

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify what is being asked. In general, try to ask more precisely, as some terms can be ambiguous. In SO, you can edit your question at any time and add the relevant information. It will be good if you add some code of what you have done and what you have attempted. As it stands now, your question is not good for the Q&A format (read the FAQ)

Comment: Does your grid display input elements (such as text boxes) or only cells with static data (spans or literal text). Tab indices in HTML can be added only on __input elements__. Really, add some of your code, as I am guessing right now. And, please, read my previous comment.

Comment: @lvaylo Slavov i have added my code for setup grid now please suggest me how to do this

Comment: please suggest me what i need to do ? do i change grid type or it can be possible with this type